# Method called in run method of a timer returns a value I need to use upstream

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice, quantifiers

I have the following timer code, and based on the execution of the run method, whether it was successful or not, I would like to return a boolean.

However I get the error message:
Local variable connected defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final.

How do I work around this to accomplish what I want?
Here is the code:

```
    private boolean getSwitchesOnRc(NamedPipeClient pipe, DV_RC_EntryPoint rc_EntryPoint, int allowedAttempts, int counter){
    final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    boolean connected = false;
    ScheduledFuture<?> countdown = scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            connected = attemptRetrievalOfSwitches(pipe, rc_EntryPoint, allowedAttempts, counter);
        }}, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);


    return connected; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to schedule a Callable rather than a Runnable to do this.

This would do what you want:

```
ScheduledFuture<Boolean> countdown = scheduler.schedule(new Callable<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean call() {
        return attemptRetrieval(...);
    }}, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

return countdown.get();
```

Note that this method will block until the scheduled call has completed.

Answer (score 1):

Just use callable insted of Runnable:

```
<V> ScheduledFuture<V>  schedule​(Callable<V> callable, long delay, TimeUnit unit)  
Creates and executes a ScheduledFuture that becomes enabled after the given delay.
```

main difference is, that Callable can return value (directly by calling return statement).

then instead of

```
return connected;
```

will be

```
return countdown.get();
```